# Как вывести изображение в VS Code?

Tags: python, matplotlib

У меня есть небольшой код:

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mnist_train = pd.read_csv("mnist_train.csv", header=None)
cols = ["label"]
for i in range(784):
    cols.append(f"px_{i}")

mnist_train.columns = cols
image_size = 28
matrix = mnist_train.values
digit = matrix[0, :]
digit = digit[1:]
digit.shape
image = digit.reshape(28 ,28)
image.shape
plt.imshow(image)
```

При запуске программы никакое изображение не появляется. Что необходимо сделать для его вывода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить `plt.show()` в самом конце.

Comment: хаха, как же все просто, спасибо)